# Multi select LOV display

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle11gr2

So, I’m struggling a bit with this one.. I’m currently using a multi select list to capture and store values in the database (colon delimited).

Example: `A:S:O`

I’d like to use a dynamic LOV to translate these values into something more meaningful.. such as:

```
Auto, Student, Other
```

However, I’m not certain of how to go about this.. I’m familiar with dynamic LOVs, but how would I handle the various combinations in varying order?

Am I forced to use `apex_item` and loop through the array? Can I somehow leverage `listagg` and/or a `connect by` statement?

I have a keys table where `KEY_NAME` stores the key (I.e. a, s, o, etc.) and `KEY_LABEL` stores the respective translation.

APEX 4.2 - oracle 11gr2

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is KEY_NAME table used for? If it contains only one column (a, s, o, ...), then KEY_LABEL (which, in that case, *must* contain those IDs with respective descriptions) should be enough.

Anyway: would something like this do any good?

```
SQL> with key_label (id, name) as
  2    -- sample labels
  3    (select 'a', 'auto' from dual union
  4     select 's', 'student' from dual union
  5     select 'o', 'other' from dual union
  6     select 'm', 'moto' from dual
  7    ),
  8  lov (value) as
  9    -- this is your LoV value
 10    (select 'a:o:s' from dual
 11    ),
 12  ones as
 13    -- LoV value transformed into rows
 14    (select regexp_substr(l.value, '[^:]+', 1, level) id
 15     from lov l
 16     connect by level <= regexp_count(l.value, '[^:]+')
 17    )
 18  -- final result (join Lov, as rows, with labels
 19  select listagg(k.name, ':') within group (order by r.id) result
 20  from key_label k, ones r
 21  where k.id = r.id;

RESULT
---------------------------------------------------------------------
auto:other:student

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice example. Couple of things.. 1.) key_name is a column, not a table. 2.) it appears that I would need to update all of my queries in order to use this solution. I’m hoping to build a dynamic LOV with APEX. Am I mistaken about your solution?

Comment: Code I posted could be rewritten into a function which would then be used in your Apex application. You'd pass "A:O:S" and get "auto:other:student". Does it mean that you have to modify all of your queries? I don't know; what solution do you use now? Not that I'm judging you, but on this year's HrOUG conference I saw a T-shirt saying "Thank you for spending months in coding and saving us days for planning".

Comment: based on that, it sounds like this won’t be an APEX “LOV” aka List of Values. I was hoping for a dynamic LOV vs. rewriting various queries (whether that be to include a function, or additional joins). Please do let me know if you feel that I’m mistaken and that this can be a true LOV. It is not my intention for you to rewrite this code.. just doesn’t look like it’s what I’m after.

Comment: I fear that the function will lead to performance issues since I’d need to call it potentially thousands of times for each page load.

Comment: I'm sorry, it appears that I'm not being helpful. I really wouldn't know whether you can, or can not do it in a simple manner. Once again, really don't want to sound rude, but the whole concept of storing combined values in a single column is a bad idea. Moreover, it violates the first normal form, so - perhaps you got something (i.e. took the opportunity of a multiple selection Apex offers), but you've also lost something. Everything would be much simpler if data model was different, but that's even worse (from point of rewriting everything). Sorry.

Comment: I truly didn’t mean for my statements to make you think that. You’ve been helpful; I enjoyed your example. It may seem as though that my structure is bad design. However, I think that in some circumstances it is ideal to store multiple values in such fashion.

Comment: Certainly; I use that too (shuttle item, that is) and then rely on a function similar to the one I suggested to you. Though, amount of data over here is tiny so I don't care about possible performance issues.